How is the most ethical way to schedule Python to run N times a day?
a question regarding quality and best practices. In a system that requires many scheduled tasks, what is the "formal" way to handle this?
When there is a number N of automation services scheduled with Python (or even Python scripts for processing data/services and delivering them periodically), where none of them follow the same business rule, what pattern/structure should I use to accommodate all these software/scripts/schedules?
Should I use crontab/task scheduler along with the code? Or should I use crontab/task scheduler to initialize the program and then implement an observer pattern to manage the scripts?
Is there any Docker solution specialized in scheduling scripts? Or specialized software for scheduling?
What’s the correct approach: pausing the script during inactivity, terminating it and restarting during active periods, or hibernating the script while clearing its CPU workload but keeping it in RAM?
I searched for a proper pattern to do this in the Python documentation, in the PEP guidelines, in agile courses, in design patterns, in microservices/API structure standards, and in clean code principles, but I never found the correct way to implement this type of script infrastructure.
I found a topic about the thing for Java 12 years ago, but it doesn't refer to the same specific subject.
Most efficient method to schedule java application to run daily

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

" all these software/scripts/schedules" is still very indefinite. That could encompass almost anything that can be scheduled. Provide a clear example of what you want to do. Although in general, just do what works. For instance, if a cron job works then that's fine. If you want to use scheduling software and find a suitable candidate, that's fine too. If you want to write your own program for handling schedules that runs as a service or daemon, thats fine too. There are many solutions to a problem like this.
